# Yii have helper/component debug class available everywhere with simple syntax and without having to import

Tags: yii, yii2

Let's say I have the Debug helper with a method to display a variable's content in a way similar to this:

```
namespace app\components;

class D extends \yii\base\Component
{
    public static function trace($variable='')
    {
        echo $variable;
    }

}
```

Is there a way for this component to be available in any `Controller`, `Model` and `View` by using its simple form and simply write:

```
D::trace($bob);
```

I would like to know if it's possible to import it everywhere so I wouldn't have to use one of these

```
// Load in config then use this (too long)
Yii::$app->D->trace($key);

// Write the whole namespace everytime (too long)
\app\components\D::trace($value);

// Load the namespace first every time I need it first (Annoying)
use app\components\D;
D::trace($value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Create helper in global namespace and add leading slash everywhere:

   ```
   \D::trace($value);
   ```
2. Create global function as a wrapper for helper (or its methods):

   ```
   function d() {
       static $d;
       if ($d === null) {
           $d = new D();
       }

       return $d;
   }

   d()->trace($string)
   ```

   or

   ```
   function dtrace($string) {
       return D::trace($string);
   }

   dtrace($string);
   ```

Comment: Thanks @rob006! You help me so much with my Yii questions, I should pay you ;)

Comment: Solution is very elegant and is perfect for me, however, I still get an exception "Class D not found" when I remove the namespace to use global

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper You need to add autoloading rules for this class: https://codingexplained.com/coding/php/composer-autoloading-third-party-libraries-without-namespaces or just `require` this file in entry script.

Comment: I was never able to make it work with composer as I'm still new to using it, even by following the link's instructions, but the entry script worked, thanks!